# How to deal with [shinyapps]/[shinyapps.io] without retagging many Q's?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

As far as I know, there are currently four tags related to shiny:

- [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny), 10.082 questions, for all shiny related questions
- [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps), 1.455 questions, which has the description `a web application framework for R`, which is basically a description for Shiny.
- [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io), 34 questions, which is used to refer to https://shinyapps.io, a hosting platform for shiny apps.
- [shinyapp.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapp.io), 6 questions. Out of the 6 questions tagged [shinyapp.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapp.io) 5 don't even deal with shinyapps.io. Let's just get rid of this one, shall we?

I think we only need two tags, one to refer to [Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/), the R package, and one to refer to https://shinyapps.io.

So in my opinion, the tag [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) is unnecessary, it is often (almost exclusively) used to tag questions related to shiny, and as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps+-shiny), practically all questions that are tagged [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) but do not have the tag [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) deal with shiny, and not with https://shinyapps.io, and should thus be tagged [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny).

So the current options seem to be:

- Keep all tags (seems weird to me, but an option nonetheless.)
- Merge [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) into [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny). This is the best option to me, looking at how the tags are used. This would leave [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) and [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io)
- Merge [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) into [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io). I think the problem with this is that a lot of existing questions will be mislabeled because of this.
- Delete [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io) manually, [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) becomes the tag for https://shinyapps.io, update its description.

Thoughts?

Comment: `shinyapps.io` looks off-topic to me. It's mostly used wrong anyway (for questions about shiny instead of questions about the hosting platform). I'd propose: Burnate [tag:shinyapps.io] and [tag:shinyapp.io], make [tag:shinyapps] a synonym for [tag:shiny].

Answer (score 19):

I want to add some statistics:

Various searches:

- [`[shinyapps] shinyapps.io`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshinyapps%5D+shinyapps.io+is%3Aquestion) 152 results
- [`[shinyapps.io] shinyapps.io`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshinyapps.io%5D+shinyapps.io+is%3Aquestion) 34 results
- [`[shiny] shinyapps.io`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshiny%5D+shinyapps.io+is%3Aquestion) 265 results
- [`[shiny] shinyapps.io -[shinyapps] -[shinyapps.io]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshiny%5D%20shinyapps.io%20-%5Bshinyapps%5D%20-%5Bshinyapps.io%5D%20is%3Aquestion) 122 results
- [`[shinyapp.io] shinyapps.io`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bshinyapp.io%5D%20shinyapps.io%20is%3Aquestion) 0 results

Though, we have the following:

- All questions with [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io) are relevant.
- Some questions (~10%) for [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) are related to [shinyapps.io](http://shinyapps.io).
- Some [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny) questions are related to `shinyapps.io`.
- But only a small part of those questions doesn't have [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) and [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io).

I think the best would be:

- Merge [shinyapp.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapp.io) into [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny). **[Status: completed.]**
- Merge [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) into [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny). **[Status: completed.]**
- Rename [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps.io) to [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) for [shinyapps.io](http://shinyapps.io). **[Status: completed.]**
- Clean the remaining questions.

---

Done step-by-step, this will leave questions related to [shinyapps.io](http://shinyapps.io) with [shinyapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shinyapps) and all other with [shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shiny).

Comment: One comment: You say all questions with [tag:shinyapps.io]  are relevant, but you do suggest to merge into [tag:shiny]?  Should we not avoid that then?

Comment: @Florian I was talking about merging [tag:shinyapp.io] (without "s") into [tag:shiny].

Comment: Oops, sorry! Now I get confused myself. All the more reason to fix this issue ;) I think this would be a good solution, although why rename the `shinyapps.io` tag to `shinyapps` and not simply leave that `shinyapps.io`?

Comment: @Florian I have check some other tags, mostly they don't name full domain: [tag:github], [tag:koding], [tag:scrapinghub]. Only when it can be confused with some other thing it uses full name: [tag:socket.io] for example.

Comment: This makes sense to me, and looking at the upvotes, most others seem to agree as well. How do we put this in motion?

Comment: @Florian I agree on the solution, but we should give more time for more R/Shiny people to get a chance to see this post, 2-3 days? A week?

Comment: @zx8754, that makes sense. Patience, not my strongest point ;)

Comment: I don't have a strong opinion--any of the options seem reasonable to me. Thanks!